# What is the best way to organize template parts?

Tags: theme-development, get-template-part

I am trying to bring some order in to theme files and would like to separate templates parts. I see that underscore ( _s ) has done something similar 
[image]

but they moved only content templates inside ,

I have several templates for header , footer, content, portfolio,

do you think that order like this would be ok

```
theme_name/
-theme-templates/
    --headers/
    --- header-centered.php
    --- header-left.php
    --- header-right.php
    --- header-menubottom.php
    --footers/
    --- footer-grid.php
    --- footer-blank.php
    --content/
    --- content-single.php
    --- content-page.php
    --- content-none.php
    --- content-search.php
    --portfolio/
    --- portfolio-full.php
    --- portfolio-split.php
```

or would I run in to some trouble ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following source codes

- [`get_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/)
- [`get_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/)
- [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

you are going to have issues, more with your custom headers and footers. I do not know what `portfolio` is and how it will be used, so I cannot answers on that specific subject

`get_footer()` and `get_header()` does not allow for custom headers and footers to be loaded from a subfolder. Looking at the source codes, the only valid file names are as follow

- For headers, it will be `header-{$name}.php` and `header.php`
- For footers, it will be `footer-{$name}.php` and `footer.php`

There are no filters to adjust this behavior in `get_footer()` and `get_header()`. There is a hackish method that you can use here though. For this to work, you will need to name your folders as follow

- For headers, you will need to name your folder `header-{whatever}`, where `{whatever}` can be anything you like
- For footers, you will need to name your folder `footer-{whatever}`, where `{whatever}` can be anything you like

(***Note:*** Using anything else than `header` and `footer` as prefix in the folder name will not work). You can then call your custom footers and headers in the following manner

```
get_header( 'whatever/header-centered' );
```

which create a filename like `header-whatever/header-centered.php`

As for template parts, I cannot see any issues right of the back. All you need to remember is to add the subfolder name as part of `$slug`

Instead of

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );
```

you will need to do the following if your subfolder is called `content`

```
get_template_part( 'content/content', 'single' );
```

Comment: thnx for the info , get_header and get_footer are used as default without any funky biz,  I was mostly concerned about get_template_part and yes , I did change the paths so all is nice and tidy now.

Comment: For the header and footer, instead of the hackish method you can ignore the get_header() method and use get_template_part() along with do_action('get_header'). Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35687331/211786